# How to extract Facebook direct Video url in HD & SD Android

Tags: facebook

I am trying to download Facebook video with both HD and SD qualitys [Like this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fb.video.downloader)

on Google play. I am beginner and don't know much more about java. I have searched a lot but can't find any solution. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

## FacebookUrlExtractor

### **`Example`**

```
  new FacebookExtractor(this,"Video Url",false)
    {
        @Override
        protected void onExtractionComplete(FacebookFile facebookFile) {
            Log.e("TAG","---------------------------------------");
            Log.e("TAG","facebookFile AutherName :: "+facebookFile.getAuthor());
            Log.e("TAG","facebookFile FileName :: "+facebookFile.getFilename());
            Log.e("TAG","facebookFile Ext :: "+facebookFile.getExt());
            Log.e("TAG","facebookFile SD :: "+facebookFile.getSdUrl());
            Log.e("TAG","facebookFile HD :: "+facebookFile.getHdUrl());
            Log.e("TAG","---------------------------------------");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onExtractionFail(Exception error) {
            Log.e("Error","Error :: "+error.getMessage());
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
```

### **`gradle`**

```
dependencies 
 {
    implementation 'com.github.Ashusolanki:FacebookUrlExtractor:0.0.5'
 }
```

For More https://github.com/Ashusolanki/FacebookUrlExtractor